# Minted using imported .m-files with å ä ö in code

Tags: minted, input-encodings, external-files

Firstly, some hopefully useful information:

- Python version: 3.8.0
- Pygments version 2.5.1
- TexLive 2019
- Texmaker 5.0.3
- Build using PDFLaTeX (tried XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX as well)
- Windows 10 (if that matters...?)

**What I want**

I am trying to import a matlab script file (*.m)  that includes characters such as **å**, **ä** and **ö** using the `minted` package.

**The issue**

What happens is that my code is imported and displayed, but said characters are missing, although a bit differently between the different engines/builders mentioned above.

That said, instead of using `\inputminted...` to import my *.m-file, everything works fine pasting the matlab-code directly inside `\begin{minted}{matlab}` ... `\end{minted}`. Meaning that my **å**'s, **ä**'s and **ö**'s are displayed correctly.

This obviously solves the issue, but I am still confused as to why the import function in `minted` does not work properly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\section{Pasted code}

\begin{minted}{matlab}
Hönökakan åts upp av änkan.
\end{minted}

\section{Imported code}

\inputminted{matlab}{test.m} % Contains the same sentence as above

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

4 error messages:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "F6.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...{n}{H�n�kakan }\PYG{l+s}{�ts upp av �nkan.}

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "F6.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...{n}{H�n�kakan }\PYG{l+s}{�ts upp av �nkan.}

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...{n}{H�n�kakan }\PYG{l+s}{�ts upp av �nkan.}

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...{n}{H�n�kakan }\PYG{l+s}{�ts upp av �nkan.}
```

Which somehow relates to the `inputenc`. These errors only arise when using PDFLaTeX (XeLaTeX only slaps my fingers for using inputenc and forgives me, but LuaLaTeX also gives me errors that proclaim that I am using an invalid utf-8 sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Sitting here writing the question made me look through the log-file to see if there was anything of value. Of course there was. The issue was not with TeX or `minted`, but the way MATLAB encodes.

```
The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool
```

Suspecting that the *.m-file I created in MATLAB (R2019) might have a different encoding I copy/pasted my code into notepad, saved it in UTF-8 (and as an *.m-file, although that might not matter) and lo and behold, now `minted` had no issues when I ran PDFLaTeX.